# What does a .dmg verify?

Tags: macos, disk-image

Whenever I open a .dmg, my computer says that it is `Verifying…` for a moment.  I'm just curious as to what it is doing at this time.  Is it running a checksum, checking if it is the same as the online version, etc.?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In most cases, your computer is just doing a checksum, to make sure the [Apple Disk Image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image), `.dmg`, hasn't been corrupted due to a flakey network connection or hard drive, or from bit-rot, etc. This can let you know about a problem early on, so you don't waste time troubleshooting a bad copy of an app.

Developers also have the [ability to codesign `.dmg`'s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824815/how-to-add-codesigning-to-dmg-file-in-mac#37923530) (thanks @graham-miln), in which case, this signature will also be verified.

Comment: Looks like zip files have checksums too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16965094/3476849